# React helmet not overriding the title and meta tags

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am developing a project in react. I have given the default title tag and meta tags in **index.html**. I am trying to update the title and meta tag for each page through props using **react-helmet**. The title tag gets updated but only for a few seconds. Whenever I change the browser tab after 5-10 secs, the title reverts back to the default value. As for the other meta tags, those tags do not override at all.

**index.html**

```
<head>
  <title>Content...</title>
  <meta name="description" content="description/>
</head>
```

**My Component**

```
<Helmet>
  <title>{this.state.meta_title}</title>
  <meta name="description" content={this.state.meta_description}/>
</Helmet>
```

I tried using ***data-react-helmet="true"***.

```
<meta name="description" content={this.state.meta_description} data-react-helmet="true"/>
```

but it didn't help. I am trying to fix this problem from last two days but no luck. If anyone can help me, please help.

**Update**

I got the solution. I was calling the **Helmet** inside the page. When I called the **Helmet** component inside the **App.js** file, it started working. The title issue is fixed but the meta tags are not updating. New meta tags get to add at the bottom of the head.

Comment: I think the `data-react-helmet="true"` bit is meant to be on the tag in the `index.html` file but apart from that, it seems fine? Anyway you produce a demo in codesandbox or something?

Comment: I tried it @TomFinney , but it didn't work. Any other suggestions?

Comment: How do you set `this.state.meta_description`?

Comment: @adesurirey, I have the meta description of all pages in a js file. Based on the URL, I am fetching the meta description from that page and assigning the value to the state meta_description.

Answer (score 8):

> data-react-helmet="true" is replace with data-rh="true" now

It's like @TomFinney said: **Just add** `data-react-helmet="true"` to tags in the `index.html`. Since [react-helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet) [identifies these elements by the attribute when you update them](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet/blob/1b57ddb1524bab195df3eeabafef67768a6d2a15/src/HelmetUtils.js#L387).

`index.html`:

```html
<title>From Index</title> <!-- title is an exception and does not require it -->
<meta name="description" content="From Index" data-react-helmet="true" />
```

`App.jsx`:

```js
<Helmet>
  <title>From Helmet</title>
  <meta name="description" content="From Helmet" />
</Helmet>
```

Works: https://e8bnj8.csb.app/ | https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-gould-e8bnj8?file=/src/App.js

You can test it by disabling javascript in your browser.

Comment: `data-react-helmet="true"` is replace with `data-rh="true"` now

Comment: @sandeep-prabhakula Maybe post an own question with your code. We need more context to help you